# Any way to connect a particular Google Sheet to Evernote using IFTTT?

Tags: google-sheets, if-this-then-that, evernote

I like and use GSheets often, but organizing the clutter is kinda difficult.

As such, I wanted to have it such that specific sheets (such as a log for my appetite and activity data) will be auto-synced with a specific note on Evernote.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Not** with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com), **but** yes with [Zapier](https://zapier.com).

The recipes IFTTT offers are much simpler, and it doesn't seem to be possible to get the new row data from the tracked sheet. It is possible though to get an update when a new row is added.

If you don't mind using another service (or combine both of them) you could use the following:
<sub>*Note: The combination would be useful if the source destination is not available on Zapier, but is on IFTTT.*

In your case, Zapier has both of the sides - the trigger and the action.</sub>

#### In Zapier:

You have **New or Updated Spreadsheet Row** as a Google Sheet trigger, and **Create Note** or **Append to Note** as an Evernote action.

- If you want to combine both IFTTT and Zapier, you can use RSS or Webhooks to create the connection.

[image: Zapier recipe]